# Restore database from .bak file with new name

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5, smo

I am sing C#, .NET 3.5, and SMO to create a copy of a database (our production database) to some other databases (our DEV and Test-database) in SQL Server 2005.

I have managed to create a backup from a database, an to restore it. this of course overwrites the existing one. I have used [this CodeProject guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMODemo.aspx).

How do I restore a backup of a database into another database, with a different name on the same server?

Comment: You have to set the Database property to the new name. You also have to make sure, that the log/data file(s) name do not macht existing ones. 
Maybe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627145/smo-restoring-to-a-different-db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

1. set the `Restore.Database` property to a new name,
2. set the `Restore.ReplaceDatabase` property to `true`,
3. specify new data and log files using the `Restore.RelocateFiles` property.

Answer (score 9):

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

string backupFile="Backupfile";//.bak file

string dbName = "DBName";

string dbServerMachineName = "MachineName";

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(dbServerMachineName);

Database database = new Database(server, dbName);

//If Need

database.Create();

database.Refresh();

//Restoring

Restore restore = new Restore();

restore.NoRecovery = false;

restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

BackupDeviceItem bdi = default(BackupDeviceItem);

bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(backupFile, DeviceType.File);

restore.Devices.Add(bdi);

restore.Database = dbName;

restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;

restore.SqlRestore(server);

database.Refresh();

database.SetOnline();

server.Refresh();
```